# Ruby & Activerecord - Working with query results

Tags: ruby, arrays, activerecord

I need help. I'm optimizing Ruby project. There are a lot of single queries so I read them at once with array of ids, example:

```
projects = Project.find_by_id(array_of_ids)
```

And I got significant improvement in speed. But the problem is when I want to search in such result, how can I work with such result?

```
p = projects .find{ |project| project.id==pr.id } # doesn't work
```

Can I convert 'projects' to array or use active-record methods further on it? 
Can I get two-dimensional array of 'projects' grouped by some parameter using Activerecord?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use the `scoped_by_*` method instead of `find_by_*` if you wanted to return an ActiveRecord::Relation object (that you can do further SQL queries on) instead of an Array.

An explanation of `scoped_by_*` can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Here's what your code should look like if you were using `scoped_by_*`.

```
projects = Project.scoped_by_id(array_of_ids)
p = projects.find(pr.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of thing you are missing over here

```
a) projects = Project.find_by_id(array_of_ids)
```

will give only one result

to get and array you need to fire query like this

```
a) projects = Project.find_all_by_id(array_of_ids)
```

Which Version of Rails are you using if Rails 3+ that what you want can be easily done with arel

```
 b) projects = Project.where("id in (?)",array_of_ids)
```

Now this would give you a relation object and you can chain your furthur query on it

If you are using Rails 2.3+ it would be better to do this using **named_scope** or **lambda**

Hope this help